# MySQL: City, state, country search

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am having trouble generating an sql query to search for cities in the following formats for an autocomplete input. The user is prompted to enter one the following formats:

1- city

2- city, country

3- city, state

4- city, state, country

My database table have the following structure

```
ID    City   State   Country
```

The query am currently using is (which is not working):

```
SELECT * FROM destinations WHERE City LIKE '%$city%' OR Country LIKE '%$country%' OR State LIKE '%$state%'
```

Where $city, $country, and $state are obtained by converting the search term from a string with commas to an array without commas. This may clarify better:

```
$query = explode(',', $term); 
$city = $query[0]; //and so on
```

Please help! I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: can you echo the query and see what all data is going to the query ?

Comment: Just as expected. The city, state, country are where they are supposed to be. I also get results but not the results I want. It only pulls the first 100 records from the DB.

Comment: you'd be better off with a fulltext index. `match(city, country, state) against 'foo bar baz'`. your `like '%...%'` will have hideous performance, because `%...%` wildcard expression prevent the use of indexes.

Comment: This could work. I'll give it a shot. Do I need to "fullindex" all of the fields?

Comment: Sorry that was a dumb question. I read an article that explains fullindex in mysql. Thank you all.

Comment: You should do some checking for the variables and adjust your query as needed based on the user input.  What happens when a user only submits a `City`?  Your query is still looking for `State` and `Country`, and those don't look to be defined.  Also, you should handle sql injection in some way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The better is full-text search.

### Why this is better than %LIKE% ?

- Much faster.
- Much more accurate.

### How it works?

Mysql going through the text, studying the words therein and maintains a separate list - which words contain the same text. When you are searching for this text field, mysql goes to the words list, quickly checking if the word you looking for exists or not, and returns the answer quickly.

In the case of `%like%`, the database would parse the text again (pull it from the file where it's saved, decrypt the string and perform a slow string comparison) .

### Limit

The full-text search is available only for Myisam tables.

Comment: I have changed my database structure to accept match-against queries. Thanks for the clarification!